# Exo Player With Cordova in IONIC Framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, exoplayer

Am getting some difficulties in dealing with Media Streaming, I have Radio Streaming Links and I tried to use Media Streaming from Cordova but it seems it have some limitations like only working in FullScreen, I came to know one plugin by name 'Exo Player' but during implementation it fails to build/run android.
Can anyone help me or tell me substitute of it.

The following error occur when I run cordova build android

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified > com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.1 > com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.5.1
  >        :android:unspecified > com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.1 > com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:r2.5.1
  >        :android:unspecified > com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.1 > com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:r2.5.1
  >        :android:unspecified > com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.1 > com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:r2.5.1
  >        :android:unspecified > com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.1 > com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:r2.5.1
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified > com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.1 > com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:r2.5.1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in the build.gradle file(highlighted in bold.)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter();
        **maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }**
    }
}
```